# EF Core Many to Many Relationship Composite key creation shows invalid Property Expression

Tags: c#

I am following the guide on msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#other-relationship-patterns

Two classes between which i need many to many relatioship:

```
public class Initiative
{
    public int InitiativeId { get; set; }
    //other properties
}
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
  //properties
}
```

My Join class :

```
 public class UserVolunteer
{
    public string userId;
    public AppUser user;

    public int initiativeId;
    public Initiative initiative;
}
```

My fluent api code :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserVolunteer>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.userId, t.initiativeId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserVolunteer>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.user)
            .WithMany(b => b.UserVolunteers)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.userId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserVolunteer>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.initiative)
            .WithMany(c => c.UserVolunteers)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.initiativeId);
    }
```

while initializing migrations, i get the following error:

> The properties expression 't => new <>f__AnonymousType0`2(userId = t.userId, initiativeId = t.initiativeId)' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.
>   Parameter name: propertyAccessExpression

I dont get whats the problem. I am doing the same as in guide and as in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class `UserVolunteer`, `userId` and `initiativeId` is a public field and not a property. Therefore it throws exception on `t => new { t.userId, t.initiativeId }` because it is not a valid property access.

```
public class UserVolunteer
{
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public AppUser user { get; set; }

    public int initiativeId { get; set; }
    public Initiative initiative { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I get it now.

Comment: I now run into the following error : The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined.

Comment: Solved it by using : base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);